# On the decomposition of $1$ as the sum of Egyptian fractions with odd denominators

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, examples-counterexamples, egyptian-fractions, computer-assisted-proofs

Suppose that we decompose $1$ as a sum of Egyptian fractions with odd denominators.

I noticed (from a cursory view) that the fraction
$$\frac{1}{3}$$
appears in each of such decompositions.

**Questions**

> Must the fraction $1/3$ appear in each such decomposition? Is it possible to prove this? Or is there a counterexample?

Comment: $1=\frac 12+\frac 14+\frac 15+\frac 1{20}$.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @lulu. But perhaps I was not clear enough: I meant that all denominators should be odd.

Comment: Ah, you did say that...I'll try for an example with that in mind.

Comment: Do you have an expression that works using $\frac 13$?  If so, perhaps you can use $\frac 13=\frac 15+\frac 19+\frac 1{45}$ to remove the $\frac 13$.  Of course the usual rules for Egyptian fractions requires that you avoid using a fraction more than once, so your expression can't have the denominators $5,9,45$ for this particular trick to work.

Comment: There are similar substitutions that might work, depending on your examples:  for instance $\frac 13= \frac 1{11}+\frac 1{13}+\frac 1{15}+\frac 1{17}+\frac 1{25}+\frac 1{91163} + \frac 1{16621293975}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and attention, @lulu!  =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1 = \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{11} + \frac{1}{13} + \frac{1}{15} + \frac{1}{17} + \frac{1}{19} + \frac{1}{21} + \frac{1}{23} + \frac{1}{25} + \frac{1}{27} + \frac{1}{33} + \frac{1}{611} + \frac{1}{265525} + \frac{1}{97544139723} + \frac{1}{8457652617058141652925}
$

Comment: Here is the [WolframAlpha verification](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2F5%29%2B%281%2F7%29%2B%281%2F9%29%2B%281%2F11%29%2B%281%2F13%29%2B%281%2F15%29%2B%281%2F17%29%2B%281%2F19%29%2B%281%2F21%29%2B%281%2F23%29%2B%281%2F25%29%2B%281%2F27%29%2B%281%2F33%29%2B%281%2F611%29%2B%281%2F265525%29%2B%281%2F97544139723%29%2B%281%2F8457652617058141652925%29) of this computation.