# Optimization on the Decomposition of 1 to unit fractions with $\frac{1}{5}$ as the largest part.

Tags: egyptian-fractions

This is a follow question to the link: [On the decomposition of $1$ as the sum of Egyptian fractions with odd denominators - Part II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3592736/on-the-decomposition-of-1-as-the-sum-of-egyptian-fractions-with-odd-denominato)

Suppose we relax the condition that any term can be divisible by 3 with the largest term of the decomposition as $\frac{1}{5}$. What is the length of the optimal decomposition? and what exactly are the odd denominators?

I have manually generated the decomposition below of 1 with 33 terms with odd denominators:

$${5,7,9,11,15,17,21,23,31,33,35,45,47,51,63,69,93,99,105,135,231,347,465,561,693,1035,1041,1683,2079,3105,4371,240471,721413}$$

Is there a lesser length and larger smallest number other than the given above?

With the link above, the length of the decomposition is 27. Since we relax the condition, can there be a decomposition less than 27?

Comment: I think you meant to say "Suppose we *replace* $\ldots$" instead of "Suppose we *relax* $\ldots$".  Nonetheless, +1!